# Memory Crash on layoutIfNeeded() during Animation

Tags: ios, swift, crash, autolayout, ios-animations

Can anyone help me diagnose this crash. It happens in the animation block on the layoutIfNeeded() function call. Full function and crash report attached.
It seems to be related to memory but I can't pin it down.

```
  private func showWarningView() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            if let safeAreaHeight = strongSelf.superview?.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.height {

                let visibleBannerHeight: CGFloat = strongSelf.isBannerVisible ? strongSelf.bannerHeight : 0

                let newConstraintConstant = (safeAreaHeight - strongSelf.externalBottomOffset - visibleBannerHeight) - strongSelf.warningBannerHeight

                strongSelf.addInternalBottomOffset(with: strongSelf.warningBannerHeight)

                strongSelf.warningViewTopConstraint.constant = newConstraintConstant

            }

            strongSelf.isWarningViewVisible = true

            let showWarningView = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.25, curve: .easeIn, animations: {

                self?.layoutIfNeeded() // <---- Crash Happens here

            })

            showWarningView.startAnimation()

        }

    }
```

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010 VM Region Info: 0x10 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4337303536
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   102860000-102864000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ... Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11 Terminating Process: exc handler [265]
```

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001d5d22f40 objc_msgSend + 32
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf72d010 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _nsis_center:bounds:inEngine:forLayoutGuide:] + 112 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3513)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf7455b0 -[UILayoutGuide _updateLayoutFrameInOwningView:fromEngine:] + 80 (UILayoutGuide.m:109)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf6c8350 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _is_layout] + 320 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3173)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf5b1a7c -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 1028 (UIView.m:12933)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf5a9fb4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2592 (UIView.m:18426)
6   QuartzCore                      0x00000001c0d20cd0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 532 (CALayer.mm:10116)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf60dd90 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 584 (UIView.m:12868)
8        ******             0x0000000102eb59d4 closure #1 in closure #1 in BottomDrawView.showWarningView() + 52 (BottomDrawView.swift:410)
9     ******                    0x0000000102eb59d4 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in BottomDrawView.showWarningView() + 68 (:0)
10    ******                    0x0000000102f33378 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (:0)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf8ee77c -[UIViewPropertyAnimator _runAnimations] + 212 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:1912)
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf78c6a4 __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke_2 + 108 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:3279)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf637fec __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke + 128 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:3267)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bfb6eba8 __49-[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:]_block_invoke.1142 + 284 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:3276)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf95fa20 -[UIViewPropertyAnimator _setupAnimationTracking:] + 132 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:3230)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf4c146c -[UIViewPropertyAnimator startAnimationAsPaused:] + 1048 (UIViewPropertyAnimator.m:3334)
17    ******                    0x0000000102eb4868 closure #1 in BottomDrawView.showWarningView() + 460 (BottomDrawView.swift:412)
18    ******                    0x0000000102f33378 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (:0)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001bcca2e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001bcca4a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001bccb2f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2622)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001bccb2b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7770)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bcff5800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bcfaf704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001bcfc2bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001d90f6374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf932648 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001bf6b3d90 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
29    ******                    0x0000000102864a08 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:22)
30  dyld                            0x0000000104505ce4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```

Comment: This seems a bit convoluted... Is this code in your view controller? And you have a "banner view" and a "warning view" as subviews of the main view? So you're trying to animate the warning view up from the bottom, to either above the banner if it's visible, or above the safe-area bottom if not?

Comment: @DonMag Yes that's exactly it. I don't think the height calculations are relevant here but included them just incase. Essentially we are setting a new top constraint constant and calling layOutIfNeeded().

Comment: Start simple... try this: https://pastebin.com/SAWT1aQg ... if that works, then start adding in your calculations.

Comment: @DonMag its not that simple to do. This code is on production and does not crash every time. I can't test on production like this.

Comment: OK - well, it looks odd to use `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to animate a constraint constant change (see my simple example)... also, I would expect this line: `self?.layoutIfNeeded()` to be `strongSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @DonMag I can try use a UIView animator but don't know if it will help. It should not be strongSelf as this is in another closure. It could cause a crash in of itself. See https://christiantietze.de/posts/2022/05/weak-self-consistency/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245948/discussion-between-davinci-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an iOS bug that was fixed with iOS 16.

Comment: can you please share the apple reference link? thanks in advance